# Flutter how to display string in Flutter Application(Android Studio Emulator)

Tags: string, flutter, dart, split

I have a problem with displaying the string output in Flutter App, I wanted to display the string value in column like this:

```
I
want
to
split
this
```

but instead I got this output:

```
[I, want, to, split, this]
```

I don't know what to do anymore as I am still new to programming, but I think this code below must be the cause:

```
void _splitWordInColumn(){
      setState(() {
        sentenceToWord.forEach((e) => print(e));
      });
      }
```

This is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtlEC.jpg) of that wrong output and below is my full code:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> sentenceToWord = 'I want to split this'.split(" ");
  
  void _splitWordInColumn(){
  setState(() {
    sentenceToWord.forEach((e) => print(e));
  });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: const Text('Flutter Demo HomePage'),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(sentenceToWord.toString()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me fix this, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `map` operator with the `column`.

```
child: Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   children: sentenceToWord.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
),
```

Comment: Thanks  it's worked! But now i wanted to display multiple string with the same method you give and i got an error "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 3 found". i tried to fix it and still got an error since yesterday, would you help me again.

Comment: Can you post your error and codes here.

Comment: I tried to solve it and i got new error: The argument for the named parameter 'children' was already specified.Try removing one of the named arguments,or correcting one of the names to reference a different named parameter.
This is the code. The error at the children word, how to solve it so that i can display more.

```children: sentenceToWord.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
children: sentenceToWord2.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
children: sentenceToWord2.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),```

Comment: You nesting the Columns like this https://pastebin.com/MyGyZ4Ff (click in the url) but this is not the good practice. If your data is huge then I would recommend you to use ListView.Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String sentenceToWord = 'I \nwant \nto \nsplit \nthis';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: const Text('Flutter Demo HomePage'),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(sentenceToWord),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```